# What is arupa jhana (5th jhana)?

Tags: personal-practice, theravada, meditation-effects

When  meditation experience mind  without body loss sensation about the environment  where I am and feel like  mind is in the sky by hearing voice  of birds.is it a jhana?

Answer (score 1):

There is no sound in jhana ([Kathāvatthu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kathavatthu)).

Comment: So what is that?